# intellij "downloading maven sources and documentation" please stop

Tags: intellij-idea

My intellij keeps saying "downloading maven sources and documentation"

I have no why it keeps saying this. Is there some way to stop intellij constantly trying to download?

Comment: Disable these options: http://i.imgur.com/jHAVeT8.png.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IntelliJ uses the sources to provide popup documentation for compliant libraries. So, when your cursor is on a library method you can press ctrl-q (on a pc) to view the quick-help window. This renders the javadocs directly from the source. If the source isn't available then this feature only shows you the details of the method signature. Intellij also uses this capability to render the documentation from your own classes.

It also uses the sources to allow you to navigate to the actual code that you're calling -- this is useful when writing code and you need to know how a library is implemented or when debugging and you want to trace inside a library.

It takes a short while to download the source for any particular library, but java apps typically have a lot of libraries so overall it can be time-consuming, but it really shouldn't take *that* long.

So, you probably want to let IntelliJ download those sources because they're really useful. You do not need to download the documents as Intellij doesn't use them.

To disable the downloading of documentation and/or sources you should look in settings at the build-tools, maven, import section. You can see it in this image (provided by @CrazyCoder in his comment on your question).

[image: Disable documentation and or sources]